# iterate over a single dimension in python dictionary

Tags: python, key, loops, dimension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iterating one key in a python multidimensional associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377908/iterating-one-key-in-a-python-multidimensional-associative-array)

i created a dictionary on 2 dimensions
    myaddresses['john','smith'] = "address 1"
    myaddresses['john','doe'] = "address 2"

How can i iterate over one dimension in the fashion

```
for key in myaddresses.keys('john'):
```

Comment: You really don't have a 2 dimensional dictionary, you have a 1 dimensional one keyed by a pair of strings...so it's not possible to do what you want unless you keep track of all the possible second halves of each first half of a key pair added. It would be better to have a 2 dimensional dict-of-dicts.

Answer (score 3):

Bad news: you can't (not directly at least). What you did was not a "2 dimensions" dict, but a dict with tuples (string pairs in your case) as keys, and only the hash value of the key is used (as usually with hashtables). What you want requires a sequential lookup, ie:

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    # no garantee we have string pair as key here
    try:
        firstname, lastname = key
    except ValueError:
        # not a pair...
        continue
    # this would require another try/except block since
    # equality test on different types can raise anything
    # but let's pretend it's ok :-/
    if firstname == "john":
        do_something_with(key, val)
```

Needless to say that it kind of defeat the whole point of using a dict. Err... what about using a proper relational DB instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
{k[1]:v for k,v in myaddresses.iteritems() if k[0]=='john'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It iterates over all keys, so it might not be the most efficient way, but I'll just state the obvious method in case you overlooked it:

```
for key in myaddresses.keys():
    if key[0] == 'john':
        print myaddresses[key]
```

Comment: i'm parsing a file and counting,totaling, testing for existence etc. If there is a syntax to get keys with a regular expression (not taking the whole key list and parsing because it may be huge) or maybe a different syntax for creating the hash (ie. myhash['apple']['green']) for keys in myhash['apple']